# Does Flash comply with HTTP Location header?

Tags: flash, http-headers

does Flash comply with HTTP Location headers? For example, if Flash makes a POST request to `http://www.example.org/mail` and it returns `Location: http://www.example.org/mail/1.xml`, will Flash return the data in in `1.xml` upon completing the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when flash is embedded in the browser, it uses the browser to do its HTTP requests. one of the reasons why many status codes never reach flash but are silently swallowed up by the browser instead.

since your browser is likely to support this, the answer is: yes